# Change product price according to visitor's country

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I want to display different prices for the product according to visitor's country.

For ex.
For product ABC: 
Price x should be displayed for country A.
Price y should be displayed for country B.
Is there any way to do it without creating any other store?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As standard, price can be set on a per website basis. In System > Configuration > CATALOG > Catalog > Price > Catalog Price Scope > Website

So, if you then set up a new website within your Magento for each country you will be able to use the configuration scope to select and set the price for each countries website.

More on creating websites can be found here: 
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/store-hierarchy.html

More on the configuration scopes can be found here: 
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html

Does this help?

Rebecca

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not want to create any other store. It should work on the same website only. Depending on site visitor's country prices should be changed.

Comment: There is this module: https://merchantprotocol.com/store/magento-extensions/magento-v1-0/advanced-pricing.html that does prices per currency and GEO location. I have never used it myself but it may be worth investigating to see if it can achieve what you want.

Comment: thanku for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set price country wise then you can create customer user group country wise and add country selection in registration form and based on country selection you need to assign user to group associated with country.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any way to get visitor's IP address and then on the basis of it change product price (Different prices for different countries) ?

Comment: That the thing i want to say magento provide user group wise product pricing so once you assign user group based on country then it will automatically show price user group wise.

Comment: I can not display country selection in registration form because I want to show different price on the basis of visitor's location i.e. country.

Comment: Need to add custom field on customer registration form for country selection and at the time of customer creation action  need to assign user group based on country selection.

Comment: You are considering the scenario while new registration but it is not needed. Because anyone can check the website without registering. So prizes should be changed irrespective of user is logged in or not.

Comment: yeah but it will be more complex to show and use price run time..it better to define on product so you don't need to change anything on front after registration and assign user group to user so once user get logged in they will get price country wise.

And as you are saying country information is available run time then no need to show country selection you just need to get it country from ip and assign group based on that.

Comment: Ok Hardik.. means do you want to say just check the visitor's IP address then get its country. According to that country display Product prices which we will save in a group??

Comment: Yes..you need to just assign customer user group based on country.

So now assign price customer group wise. so whenever user with particular group logged in price will be visible of that customer's group.

Comment: If customer is not logged in then also I want to show the price according to country!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41250/discussion-between-vedu-and-hardik-shah).